# Bug in binary search tree insertion code

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I was trying to use to insert into a binary tree using while loop. However it seems to have a bug: it only takes the first number and doesn't take the rest. I don't know where I made the mistake.

I've created the following code:

```
void BTC::Insert(int Data)

{Node *newNode = new Node;



if (head == 0)
{
    head = node;
}
else
{
    Node* ptr = head;

    if(ptr->childs>2)
    {   
        if (Data > ptr->data)
        {
            ptr->right = node;
        }
        else if (Data <= ptr->data)
        {
            ptr->left = node;
        }
        ptr->childs++;
    }
    else
    {
       While(ptr->childs==2)
        {
        if (Data > ptr->data)
           {
             ptr = ptr->right;
           }
        else if (Data <= ptr->data)
           {
             ptr = ptr->left;
           }
        }
    }
}

class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node* right;
    Node* left;
    int childs;
    Node() : right(0), left(0)
    {}

    Node(int data) : data(data), right(0), left(0),childs(0)
    {}


}
}
```

Comment: please elaborate what you mean by bug. provide some test case or scenario.

Comment: It is because no update of non-local data will occur when `head != 0 && head->child <= 2`. I guess you should use loops or something.

Comment: What is `node`? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: because in your method of insertion using **loop** there is no loop. It doesn't iterates through the tree.

Comment: sorry i posted the wrog code now i fixed it @Optimus1072

Comment: again the problem is with positioning of loop if `ptr ->childs > 2` it will not go down in the tree. @NoureldinTarek

Comment: @Optimus1072 sorry mate but if i know where to put the loop i wouldn't post anything here so please if you know where i can put it to work tell me because i must send this to my TA in 2 hours